# My (very simple) program seems to exhibit weird behavior when my fgets input exceeds the specified buffer size

Tags: c, fgets

I'm just getting started with C and I've written a very simple program that takes an Employee ID, hours worked and salary and outputs the wage earned and ID given.

I'm capturing the ID with fgets, however, when I enter a string of characters longer than the specified buffer size (of 10 here) my program seems to "crash". It prints the next two printf's on the same line, skipping taking input for the first, which obviously breaks the program.

When the ID captured with fgets is <= the buffer size it works fine. A little confused as to what the issue is. FWIW I'm using codeblocks with the GNU GCC Compiler.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Initialize variables
    char ID[11];
    float hrs, sal;

    // Get Employee's ID from user input
    printf("Input the Employee's ID(Max. 10 chars): ");
    fgets(ID, sizeof(ID), stdin);

    // Get working hours as float from user input
    printf("Input the working hrs: ");
    scanf("%f", &hrs);

    // Get hourly salary as float from user input
    printf("Salary amount/hr: ");
    scanf("%f", &sal);

    // Print Employee's ID
    printf("Employee's ID: %s", ID);

    // Print wage based on hours worked and salary
    printf("Salary = U$ %.2f", sal * hrs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is, that the rest of the line is not fetched by `fgets()` if it's larger than the passed buffer and hence remains in the input buffer of your stdin filestream; subsequently the conversions of `scanf()` fail.

You would have to detect this case (for example by checking, if the last character in your just-read string is not a newline) and empty the input buffer up to the next newline, for example by calling `getchar()` in a loop up to a newline (or EOF). Then call `scanf()`.

Example code (untested and EOF-check still missing):

```
fgets(ID, sizeof(ID), stdin);
if (ID[strlen(ID)-1] != '\n') {
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        ;
}
```

And remember to check the return values of your `scanf()` calls to see, if the conversions succeeded!

Comment: Rather than `ID[strlen(ID)-1] != '\n'`, suggest `strchr(ID, '\n') == NULL` to prevent UB when the first character read by `fget()` is a _null character_.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you observe is because if the newline is not written to ID because there is no room, it remains in the input buffer, which the subsequent two `scanf()` calls do not consume due to the format specifier string not reading white space.

`fgets()` returns when a newline is entered, *and* the newline is written to the buffer.  That being the case you requiire a buffer of 12 characters - the accommodate the newline and the nul terminator.  It is a good idea to zero initialise the buffer too.

```
char ID[11] = {0} ;
```

After the `fgets()`, you may need to replace the newline with a nul.

To replace the newline with nul or discard the input buffer data where the newline remains:

```
char* end = strrchr( ID, `\n` ) ;
if( end != NULL) 
{ 
    *end = `\0` 
}
else
{
    char c ;
    do
    {
        c = getchar() ;
    } while( c != '\n' && c != EOF ) ;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `int ch` than `char ch` to properly detect `c != EOF`.